# Update to "undeliverable" status from subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, import, subscriber

I was facing the issue of importing a list to "All Subscribers" with the status Undeliverable. The problem is that the keyword "Undeliverable" do not exist in order to update the subscriber status. I've tried with "Held" and "Bounced" as well but doesn't work (error "InvalidContextStatus    Invalid Context Status").

Anyone know what is the status to update the subscribers?

I know that using API calls we can do it (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/subscriberstatus.htm). But in this case, I would like to update the status with bounce using import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, the only two status values that an end user is able to set is either 'Unsubscribed' or 'Active'.  According to Global Support, the other two statuses are for internal (SFMC) use only.  To be able to manipulate or otherwise make use of Bounce/Held, you would need to create different global suppression lists for each and import/edit these accordingly.